# Regex regular-expression Java String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have code:

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<p>(.+?)</p>");
private static List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
    final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return tagValues;
}
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(stringText).toArray()));
```

and i want get from this:

```
"<html><head></head><body><p>Aa , aa.</p><p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p><p>Aa aa aa, aa.</p><p><i>Aa, aa.</i></p><p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></body></html>"
```

I want only the text beetwen `<p>` and `</p>`

```
i want get only this: 

"Aa aa Aa aa aa Aa aa aa aa Aa aa B b b"
```

But i don't know what i have to write in `Pattern.compile("");`anyone help?

Comment: this  `<b>Aa aa, aa.</b>` can be between `<p>` and `</p>`

Comment: `Jsoup` can also pick all the `p` tags data but again issue will be this `<b>Aa aa, aa.</b>` because is not inside `p` and somewhere you also have `b` tag inside `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Pattern nor Matcher for that, you could do a String replace instead:

`str.replaceAll(".*?(<p>.*</p>).*", " $1 ").replaceAll(".*?<p>(.*?)</p>.*?", " $1 ").replaceAll("<[/a-z]+>", " ").replaceAll("[,.]", " ").replaceAll(" +", " ")`

It doesn't look pretty but it gets the job done :)

Comment: thanks it is helpful but i add some edit to my post because outpus was wrong, i don't need <b>Aa aa, aa.</b> in my output, so you know what i must edit you code that it will work?

Comment: I've update my answer to align with the edit to your answer. Please up-vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: " \$1 " this give me a error in eclipse, `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )` this is error

Comment: I've fixed my answer. Please try now

Comment: Yes it works ! Thank you. Is it any site where i put the text and it return the characters that i have to enter ?  like this : `replaceAll(".*?(<p>.*</p>).*", " $1 ")` ? Or i have to learn all characters what it means?

Comment: I don't believe there is any site that will create a regular expression for you. You can learn about Java regex in their documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use `JSOUP` parser to extract your data from `HTML` code

1.) Parse your data as `Document` using `Jsoup.parse(string)` function.

2.) Get the data of `body` tag as `Element`.

3.) Fetch the text of `Element` tag using `element.text()`.

4.) Optionally you can use `replaceAll("\\s*[,.]\\s*","")` to remove all commans and dots and format spaces.

```
    String stringText = "<html><head></head><body><p>Aa , aa.</p><p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p><p>Aa aa aa, aa.</p><p><i>Aa, aa.</i></p><p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></body></html>";
    Document document =Jsoup.parse(stringText);
    Element element=document.body();
    String plain_String = element.text().replaceAll("\\s*[,.]\\s*"," ");
    System.out.println(element.text()); // Actual text
    System.out.println(plain_String);   // Formatted text
```

Output :

```
Aa , aa. Aa aa, aa. Aa aa aa, aa. Aa, aa. B, b, b.Aa aa, aa.
Aa aa Aa aa aa Aa aa aa aa Aa aa B b b Aa aa aa
```

[Download Jsoup](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsoup160jar.htm) and add it as a dependency

`\\s*[,.]\\s*` :`\\s*` match zero or more spaces

`[,.]`         : match any character mentioned inside `[]` mean `,.`

---

If you insist the `regex` solution then use

1.) First remove all unwanted characters like `,.` and spaces with `replaceAll("\\s*[.,]\\s*", " ")`

2.) Use regex [`<p[<>ib]*>([\\w\\s]+)<\\/[\\w]>`](https://regex101.com/r/pLkblg/1) with `Pattern` and `Matcher` to find your text between tags

3.) Append the found text in `StringBuilder` and display the result

Code

```
    String str = "<html><head></head><body><p>Aa , aa.</p><p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p><p>Aa aa aa, aa.</p><p><i>Aa, aa.</i></p><p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></body></html>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<p[<>ib]*>([\\w\\s]+)<\\/[\\w]>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str.replaceAll("\\s*[.,]\\s*", " "));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        builder.append(matcher.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
```

Output :

```
Aa aa Aa aa aa Aa aa aa aa Aa aa B b b
```

Comment: just in case , if you want all `p` tags data , use `document.getElementsByTag("p").text()` but again resultant string will not include `<b>Aa aa, aa.</b>` text data because it's not inside `p` tag

Comment: yes i edit my post that i want this text without <b>Aa aa, aa.</b> but i can;t use this Jsuop because i must send only file in java without jsoup

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
String str = "<html><head></head><body><p>Aa , aa.</p><p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p><p>Aa aa aa, aa.</p><p><i>Aa, aa.</i></p><p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></body></html>";
String start = ">", end = "<";
String regexString = Pattern.quote(start) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(end);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str.replaceAll("[.,]", ""));
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (!matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim().equals("")) {
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ") + " ");
    }
}
```

This gives you :

```
Aa aa Aa aa aa Aa aa aa aa Aa aa B b b Aa aa aa
```

Comment: thanks it is helpful but i add some edit to my post because outpus was wrong, i don't need <b>Aa aa, aa.</b> in my output, so you know what i must edit you code that it will work?